# I am really new in ubuntu. I just downloaded the iso file. Can any one suggest me the best partitioning?

Tags: partitioning

My hdd is 500 gb and 4 gb of ram

Answer (score 3):

What is best really depends upon your needs.

Many people use dual-boot, so the they can use the same computer with two different Operating Systems, such as Ubuntu and Windows or OS/X.

In such a case, 250gb each is a reasonable initial setup. If using Windows, load it first, then get Ubuntu to partition the disk. Be prepared to experiment a bit.

If you just want to use the computer for Ubuntu, use the whole disk. You can still use another Operating System inside a VM, such as VirtualBox.

Comment: Partitioning can get more complex than just designating half to each OS, as each often can have multiple partitions. For instance with Ubuntu it is possible to have a boot, root, and swap partitions, alongside shared NTFS partitons if dual booting.

Comment: Yes, that's true, and it's good to give the heads up to the OP. My thinking is that *what's best* is determined by his requirements. Presumably he knows if he has more sophisticated needs.